# How to view veoh.com videos with HT03-A Android

Tags: video, android, ffmpeg

It is not possible to be able to watch videos of veoh in iPhone ,but android is not able to

Can I convert videos with ffmpeg?

If there is a method else, give me information

Comment: Are you referring to an iPhone running Andriod or a feature of veoh? *Confuses says: This makes much sense no?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the exception of some m4v files, I have yet to have a problem watching iPod converted video files on the g1. See [this](https://superuser.com/questions/5784) for tools that do iPhone conversion.